# MVC3:Are Areas intended for this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have to code a web portal that offers multiple and varied features such as: notification and resolution of user problems, purchasing requests, requests for supplies, facilities management ...

I thought I should create an MVC application and divide it by creating an area for common things and a separate area for each of the other features, but do not know whether the concept of area is suitable for my needs or is intended for other needs.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Areas will separate parts of your site into directories where each area/folder has their related views and controllers.

Areas also help separate your application in the URL structure.

I don't think there is a hard rule of when to use Areas and when not to, most commonly though I would say it depends on the size of your application. A site with only a few pages would not realy need any areas, that might be overkill in design.

Comment: I agree with François. Areas in MVC allow you to partition large applications into smaller segments that are all hosted in a single project. The biggest advantages of areas are 1) you can split an application into sections managed by different teams or developer or 2) split your app into sections which have different dependencies or requirements than the rest of the app and 3) general code organisation benefits.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

By your responses I think I could use areas.

A greeting.